# How to reposition a Path Line in paperjs with best efficiency?

Tags: performance, animation, canvas, line, paperjs

quick question about **line repositioning** with Paper.js.
I started to play a bit with this library and I found it very interesting for small kind of animation but sometimes the documentation is not really the best ever.
Anyway, my goal is to move a line.

This is my code to create it

```
a_lines[(i -1) / 2].line = new Path.Line({
    from: a_lines[(i -1) / 2].start,
    to: a_lines[(i -1) / 2].end,
    strokeColor: '#282828'
});
```

and this is the one I invented to use it to move it:

```
a_lines[(i -1) / 2].line.removeSegment(0);
a_lines[(i -1) / 2].line.add(a_lines[(i -1) / 2].start);
a_lines[(i -1) / 2].line.removeSegment(0);
a_lines[(i -1) / 2].line.add(a_lines[(i -1) / 2].end);
```

It works fine, but I am asking if I really need to to this operation with four command lines. At the moment is the best solution I found. But has somebody better and more efficient solutions?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is in the right direction; deleting a line and recreating it is slower than just manipulating the segment points. But you can do a bit better by merely altering the existing segment points.

```
line = a_lines[(i - 1) / 2].line;
line.segments[0].point = newStartPoint;    // repositioning as you like
line.segments[1].point = newEndPoint;      // ditto
```

Here's a simple sketch showing it work without any extraneous code:

[Segment Point manipulation sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/VU49D4JADP0rzS1AQghqHMA46aiJiYPDwcBHlctBa+AIA+G/W2WyQ/M++l46Kyo6VKm6W3RVo0JVcf3lGbWGEI5AOMGtcE10Ee7rJA4hifMQ9HYvUFYeHNbjaHA9Wzxxy70EvbItKuv9mw9Tu0bMncgZPUeqnGECpiuPA555Ih8DmDMCmTWHrw7JDXqTR2825CSNK5KORT4ueyzsTxhUqvPlAw==)

[Slightly modified Segment Point manipulation sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/VU+xDoJADP2V5hYhIQQ1DmCMg46amDg4AAOcVS5Aa+AIA/HfLV4c7NC+177XppOiokWVqGuNVlcqUJrvM8+oMYSwA8IRLoWtwpNwL42jAOIoDyBdbQRKyv2tE4e97bjGAzfciXFRNoWuF//Dm7nbSoZraWc0VkbPbJnRYyBtDRMwnXno8cgjeejDlBFIuBX4bJFsn359efhiQ1bs6NDWSX9LXd1DBMl84C2/lR0W9VfbqyTN3x8=)